# Figure appears in bibliography

Tags: floats

i used all possible options for the figure placement [h], [!h], [ht], [htb]
and the figure always appears in the middle of the bibliography, since the figure is near the end of the paper.

is there an option to "flush" everything before the bibliography?

So it would even look something like

[NEW PAGE]
bla bla bla
[some vertical space]
[NEW PAGE]
[figure]
bibliography

because now it looks like:

[NEW PAGE]
bla bla bla
bibliograhy
[NEW PAGE]
[figure]
bibliography (continuing)

Comment: you could add `\clearpage` before your `bibliography`, or else `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins` package. There's a question that covers this on the site, I'll find it in a minute

Comment: have a look at any of the questions in [keeping floats in their section](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=keeping+floats+in+their+section&submit=search), particularly Frank Mittelbach's [stellar answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 17):

The simplest way to flush floats is `\clearpage` which outputs all floats (potentially on new pages) and afterwards starts a new page.

If a new page is not desired then the use of the package `placeins` will help. It offers a command `\FloatBarrier` that forces floats to be placed before further text will be typeset. It offers some finer control through package options.

Also something like `[!t]`might help (which was not listed in your placement options you tried), as it turns off some of the restrictions for placing the current float on the top of the page.